# Would US Based client pursue legal action against a someone impersonating a candidate?

Tags: interviewing, india, legal, software

I joined in a MNC and got my first round interview invitation link from US Based client
with this extra details:

> “This interview invitation is intended for the candidate to whom this
> [email / letter]  is addressed. In the event of any impersonation of
> the intended candidate, XYZ company will not  hesitate to report the
> impersonation to the **police** and/or  other authorities in addition to
> any **legal action** which it may take against the impersonator  and/or
> the intended candidate.”

Would US Based client pursue legal action against a someone impersonating a candidate?

Comment: I get the impression that there are English fluency issues that are making your question unclear. If you're asking whether a company would pursue legal action against a someone impersonating a candidate, I don't understand what the "just for one" part means. They are probably interviewing multiple clients, and don't want any of them impersonated. Also, "legally" usually means "not a crime", not "involving the legal system"; which meaning predominates depends on context, but here the normal interpretation would be the former.

Comment: Why do you care? Are you planning on committing fraud?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Of course **No**.

Comment: @Acccumulation I edited question with clear English.

Comment: It clearly reads that they say they will take action. What level and how far is up to them.

Answer (score 2):

> Would US Based client pursue legal action against a someone impersonating a candidate?

Extremely unlikely. It costs a lot of effort and money and there is nothing to gain in return.

This is just legal boilerplate generated by a lawyer thinking in lawyer terms.

Answer (score 1):

> Would US Based client pursue legal action against a someone impersonating a candidate?

Well, they clearly *say they will*. Whether that is what will actually happen in the future, none of us can answer. Maybe. Whether impersonating someone else *with their consent* is a crime in your jurisdiction, and which one and what penalty it carries, is something you should consult a local lawyer about.

That said, it is hard to pull off a scam against a target that is warned and skeptical. This one clearly is. It might not be wise to attempt it, from a purely economical point of view of risk versus reward.

Comment: Why wife worked in recruiting and they definitely interviewed and hired people speaking perfect English, then the person turning up to work with customers didn’t speak a word English.

Comment: Getting a job by hiring someone who passes the interview for you is most likely fraud.

Answer (score 0):

This is a legal question, which better fits "**Law StackExchange**" at: https://law.stackexchange.com/

The company may or may not pursue that option, depending on whether the impersonation really hurts their company financially or their reputation. If there is no real damage to their company in any way, then they may ignore this impersonation to save time and money.

---

**Please note that this following paragraph does not imply that the OP wants to cheat.** :-)

It is just a general piece of advice.

The point is that the candidates should not cheat by asking someone else to take the interviews for them.

**The first reason** is that if the candidates pass the interviews by asking someone else taking the interviews for them, then if they get the job, they will likely not have enough skills and experiences. This deficiency may show up very quickly during the first work assignment, and the managers may let these employees go pretty soon.

**The second reason** is that the companies may also take the pictures of the interviewees, and later compare those pictures with the photos of the candidates who get the job offers. Here are some possible scenarios:

**1. Online Coding Test**:

Lots of online coding test websites (such as Codility, Hackerrank, etc...) may require test takers to turn on the webcam on the computers while taking the tests. Then, during the tests, the software will automatically and randomly take a photo of the test takers once every 20 seconds or so.

**2. Onsite interviews**:

When you enter the physical offices for in-person interviews, the security cameras of these companies will automatically record your images as you walk around the hallway, or go in and out of the offices for interviews.

**3. Online video interviews (Zoom/Microsoft/Google):**

**Depending on the country or location**, many companies may or may not even need to ask for the permission to take pictures of the interviewees (screenshots) during the online video interviews for the interview records. Or, they may have some small fine-print somewhere to say that they need to take the photos of the interviewees for the interview records, and require you to give the permission.